# How do I split 30 GB Outlook 2003 .PST file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, pst

I have 400 GB of files that I need to split and burn on DVDs for HR, but I have few PSTs that are 20+ GB.

How can I split these huge PST files?

Comment: Wow, didn't even know it was even possible to create PSTs that big with Outlook 2003 without them getting corrupted all the time!

Comment: Seems it's possible! Imagine... old laptop w/ 40GO HDD. The user has Windows XP with Office 2003, home software AND 30go OST files!

Comment: go == giga octets == giga byte ? (thanks to @DMA57361 http://chat.superuser.com/transcript/message/18219#18219 )

Comment: In Montreal, Canada, we use GO for size. Gbytes is mostly used for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the files using [HJSplit](http://hjsplit.en.softonic.com/), or create spanning archives using 7zip.